Timeseries Transformer for Custom Dataset
I am trying to try something using a transformer from HuggingFace. Specifically the Time Series Transformer. I can't seem to figure out how to initialize it and just run a single forward pass. My dataset is basically this: torch.rand(num_samples, timesteps, features)
This is generally the code I am trying to get to work. I have went through the docs and the parameters many times but I am probably missing something.
from transformers import (
    TimeSeriesTransformerConfig,
    TimeSeriesTransformerForPrediction,
)
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch

dataset = torch.rand(1000, 300, 61)
dataloader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=4)

config = TimeSeriesTransformerConfig(prediction_length=24, input_size=61)
model = TimeSeriesTransformerForPrediction(config=config)

for batch in dataloader:
    outputs = model.forward(
        past_values=batch,
        past_time_features=torch.arange(1, 300).expand(4, -1),
        past_observed_mask=torch.ones_like(batch),
    )
    print(outputs)

What I want to predict is the next timestep(s) of 61 features. I am probably initializing the model in a way that is incompatible with my data but I am not very familiar with these types of models.
How to get this to work?
